# XSLT: Add text inside html tag

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to add text from a xsl variable to the inside of a html tag something like this?

```
<xsl:variable name="selected">
   <xsl:if test="@class = 'selected'"> class="selected"</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<li{$selected}></li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:element name="li">
    <xsl:if test="@class = 'selected'">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            selected
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
```

Optionally, the `xsl:if` could be nested in the `xsl:attribute`, instead of the other way around, if a `class=""` is desired. As already mentioned, it is unwise to write this as literal text.

Comment: For readability, it's best to avoid unnecessary xsl:element calls and embed the li element directly.

Answer (score 5):

You should not attempt to write this as literal text, instead look at xsl:element and xsl:attribute.  Rough example:

```
<xsl:element name="li">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="$selected" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

[Full documentation here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-and-Attributes)

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you are careful enough to make it its first child, you can use `<xsl:attribute>` directly inside of your `<li>` tag, instead of using `<xsl:element>`

```
<li>
    <xsl:if test="$selected">
        <!-- Will refer to the last opened element, li -->
        <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- Anything else must come _after_ xsl:attribute -->
</li>
```